# Smoothly Changing Animation Speed on Hover?

Tags: css, performance, animation, scale, transition

I'm having issues with properly changing the pace of a scaling animation of mine on hover - every time I hover, the animation jumps to the first keyframe, the opposite of smooth.

The animation rapidly scales a letter up and down, "breathing", so to speak. On hover, this should slow down.

I've tried pausing and running the slower animation on hover, but that just moves the letter around inconsistently...

Here's an excerpt out of my Code! (Note that this is part of a larger project and styled accordingly.)

CSS:

```
.r {
font-size: 590.4px;
color: #252122;
margin-left: -39.36px;
margin-top: -189.58px;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0%);
text-align: center;
animation-name: breathe;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 0.8s;
}

.r:hover{
animation-duration: 4s;
transition-property: animation-duration;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
} 

@keyframes breathe{
0% {transform: scale(1)}
50% {transform: scale(1.2)}
100% {transform: scale(1)}    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper-r">
     <div class="r">r</div>
</div>
```